Probability of 4th customer choosing new menu item
I have a probability question related to a fast food restaurant scenario. The restaurant has 5 menu items. Four customers come in and each chooses one item at random. I want to determine the probability that the 4th customer orders an item that none of the previous three customers have ordered.
Details:

There are 5 distinct menu items numbered 1 to 5.
Each of the first three customers can independently choose any of the 5 items with equal probability.
I’m interested in finding the probability that the 4th customer chooses a menu item that is different from those selected by the first three customers.

What I've considered:
I believe I can calculate the probability based on the outcomes of the first three customers' selections, $\mathbb{P}(X_4=i|X_1≠i,X_2≠i,X_3≠i)$
i.e., the probability that the 4th customer chooses item $i$, given that each previous customer has chosen a distinct item. Is it necessary to calculate this for all $i=1,2,3,4,5$, or would calculating for just one $i$ be enough? Also, I am wondering if there is a way to use conditional probability or if there is a simpler way to approach the problem, perhaps using a multinomial distribution or a symmetry argument?
Any guidance on how to approach this problem or the correct probability calculation would be greatly appreciated!

This is a self-study question, please elaborate on your approach and which difficulties you face to reach a solution.

Hi @Xi'an, thanks for the comment. The difficulty I'm facing is understanding how to calculate the probability: $P(X_4 = i , | , X_1 \neq i, X_2 \neq i, X_3 \neq i)$
i.e., the probability that the 4th customer chooses item i, given that each previous customer has chosen a distinct item.
Is it necessary to calculate this for all $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, or would calculating for just one $i$ be enough? Also, I am wondering if there is a way to use conditional probability or if there is a simpler way to approach the problem, perhaps using a multinomial distribution or a symmetry argument?

Hint: the order is a red herring.  So, let customer four choose an item.  What is the chance the three previous customers each chose a different item?

`please edit the question rather than answering in the comments

Hi @whuber, thanks for the hint! If I understand correctly, the probability doesn't change based on the order in which customers make their choices. So, for the 4th customer to choose an item that hasn’t been selected, we only need to calculate the probability that the first three customers have all chosen different items beforehand.
Would that mean I should calculate the probability that the first three customers choose distinct items first and then multiply by the probability that the 4th customer picks a new item?

I don't follow that, because your question does not concern cases where the first three customers chose distinct items.  It only concerns cases where they chose items that differ from customer four's choice.

Where does this question come from? Is it a puzzle book, a homework question?

@SextusEmpiricus, it comes from: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/570450471d07c094a39efaed/t/58b093b037c581bd4b6cf61b/1487967152490/PUMaC2010_CombinatoricsASol.pdf
I saw their solution but I don't understand how they did it.

That's not even a probability question--it's purely about counting all the possibilities.

There are (at least) three ways to tackle this problem.

Straightfoward: Don't try to be smart and grind out the computations. You can do this by considering the sum of the probabilities of the events.

the first three guests chose 1 unique menu item and the fourth chose different
the first three guests chose 2 unique menu item and the fourth chose different
the first three guests chose 3 unique menu item and the fourth chose different

These can all be computed as a product of a binomial distribution with a Bernouli distribution.

more extremely simplistic: write out all possible $5^4=625$ options and count which cases apply.

Rephrasing the problem: The event that the fourth chose a different item from the previous three, is the same as the event that the previous three chose a different item from the fourth.
Don't bother about what has already been chosen by. Instead consider the case that the fourth customer wrote their menu choice on a piece of paper before the others made their order. What is the probability that any of the other three have a different menu choice.



we only need to calculate the probability that the first three customers have all chosen different items beforehand. Would that mean I should calculate the probability that the first three customers choose distinct items first and then multiply by the probability that the 4th customer picks a new item?

Change it into this: we only need to calculate the probability that the first three customers have all chosen different items compared to the decision made by the fourth. That means you should calculate the probability that first the 4th customer picks a item, then the other three customers choose distinct items.
Consider the situation where all customers made their choices, then first customer 4 reveals their choice, then 3, then 2 , then 1. What is the probability that customer 3, 2 and 1 are all different from customer 4?
